# JQuery stopPropogation with .on('click') binding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to prevent the button click from bubbling up to the table row event, but I can't seem to prevent it from happening.

So, basically, I have a table row, which is clickable, and takes you to a different screen.

AND i have a button on the row, which executes the below function, and returns data via AJAX, and refreshes the page.

Here is my JQuery function for the button:

```
$('#check_container').on('click', '.edit-risk-compliance', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // tried this on its own, and together with below
    e.stopPropagation(); // tried this on its own, and together with below
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // tried this on its own, and together with below

    // capture course_id from clicked button
    var risk_type_id = $(this).attr('id');

    // change type 1 = exclude, change type 2 = include
    var change_type = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + 'risk/amend_risk_compliance',
        data: "risk_type_id=" + risk_type_id + "&change_type=" + change_type,
        success: function (data) {

            $('#check_container').html(data);

        }
    });

});
```

Here is the function for the row click:

```
$('#table_holder').on('click', '.risk_log_row', function() {
    // capture risk_type_id from clicked button
    var risk_type = $(this).attr('id');
    // redirect to controller to show privileges
    window.location = '/risk/manage_questions/' + risk_type;
});
```

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="row" id="check_container">
        <div id='table_holder' class="col-md-12" >
            <table id="risk_log_table" class="sortable table table-striped tablesorter">                                        
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Risk Assessment</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    <tr id='4' class='risk_log_row clickable'>
                        <td data-title='Risk Assessment'>Agency Workers</td>
                        <td data-title='Actions'>
                            <div id='4' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit risk renewal period' class='edit-freq-btn btn risk-btns btn-info btn-sm'>Edit Renewal</div>
<div id='2' data-id='2' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Include in compliance' class='edit-risk-compliance btn btn-primary btn-sm'>In compliance?</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why not only attach `$('#table_holder').on('click', '.risk_log_row', function(e) {` and test the e.target is the button

Comment: You're using event delegation, so the click handler on `#table_holder` is getting called before the one on `#check_container`. It doesn't matter what you've put into the selector argument.

Comment: `'.edit-risk-compliance'` doesn't exist in your HTML

Comment: @ScottSelby sorry, i emitted that by mistake

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have tried changing the handler to #check_container on both. It didn't make any difference

Comment: @frobak , it's a big mistake , if that element doesn't really exist as a child of `#check_container` then you are not attaching the click event to a lower level nested element and therefore the other click handler fires first.   You can always try `.off()` first to remove all other handlers then do you `.on()`

Comment: @ScottSelby it was in the code, but when i was cutting it down for the purpose of this post, i accidentally removed too much of the html

Comment: @frobak I tried changing the selector of the calls to [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) to match and it appears to help (and doesn't require the call to stopImmediatePropagation() - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aelliott/pdvnj4d1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you attach the click event to the button, like

```
$('.edit-risk-compliance').on('click',  function(e) {
```